# Como permitir que um evento atinja outros elementos de UI?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Eu possuo um `xaml` que aplico um retângulo sobre várias imagens, com o intuito de poder manipula-las após um holding nelas. O problema é que, caso eu coloque o `IsHitTestVisible` em estado `false` no retângulo e, quando uma das imagens disparar o `Holding`, eu atualize o estado do `IsHitTestVisible` para `true`, o retângulo na dispara eventos, como `ManipulationDelta`, sendo necessário retirar o dedo da  *touchscreen* e colocá-lo de novo para disparar os eventos no meu retângulo.

O que eu tenho de problema é semelhante a [essa pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631714/forward-tap-event-to-uielement-behind-another-uielement), apesar de não ter resposta, eles citam técnicas de reflexão e o uso de `routed events`, no entanto não resolveu o meu problema por eu não saber usar corretamente ou por realmente não ser a solução adequada. Poderiam me dar exemplo de como fazer para resolver esse problema?

Comment: Poste o `XAML` para facilitar o entendimento. @felipe-avelar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar muito, a solução encontrada foi utilizar o [`VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838303%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Daí o que foi feito foi o seguinte: Primeiro deixamos ativo o retângulo que está sobre as imagens e adicionei o evento de `Holding` nele, depois utilizo o `FindElementsInHostCoordinates` pra encontrar as imagens debaixo dele e disparar o evento de `Holding` para o "filho" correto, já que eu consigo pegar todos os elementos de interface que estão sob o meu dedo. Acredito que essa seja a melhor maneira, mas, caso alguém tenha uma melhor, por favor, compartilhe.